# CreateProcessAsUser() not working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to start GUI application using my service. I developed the service on VS2012 and running on windows 7. But CreateProcessAsUser function doesn't start application even though it returns successfully. following is my code:

```
PHANDLE hToken = NULL;
WTSQueryUserToken (WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId (), hToken) ;

if( !CreateProcessAsUser( hToken,
    NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    pPath,          // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
 )
```

what could be the issue?

Thanks,
KM.

Comment: Suggest you extend snippet to show what hToken, pPath, si and pi are

Comment: When a system function fails, you should use [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out what went wrong. See [here for lists of error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and what they mean.

Comment: MSDN says *"Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization. If a required DLL cannot be located or fails to initialize, the process is terminated"*, which may be worth consideration.

Comment: Previously I was using CreateProcess from console application to start another app and it was working fine with same si,pi and pPath. but calling CreateProcessAsUser from service fails. It gives me the feeling that the problem has something to do with access user token. any idea?

Comment: Does `WTSQueryUserToken` succeed and give you a valid token with the required access rights?

Comment: Did you init the structures ? `ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));` and `ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));`

Answer (score 2):

After retrieving the user token from `WTSQueryUserToken()`, call `DuplicateTokenEx()` to convert it into a primary token, and pass that token to `CreateProcessAsUser()`.  You also need to specify the "winsta0\default" (use: `"winsta0\\default"`) desktop via the `STARTUPINFO` structure. You should also call `CreateEnvironmentBlock()` using the same token, and pass that environment to `CreateProcessAsUser()` as well.

Comment: `WTSQueryUserToken` already return primary token. not need duplicate it

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to be sure of my answer but that kind of error often happen when the structures are not correctly initialized.

```
PHANDLE hToken = NULL;
WTSQueryUserToken (WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId (), hToken) ;

//be sure that the handle is correct ! (can be the issue)
if (!hToken) printf("Token error.\n");

//init here !
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if( !CreateProcessAsUser( hToken,
    NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    pPath,          // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while using `WTSQueryUserToken` in windows 7, but the same function worked in windows 10.

So I took the `explorer.exe` token, called the `DuplicateTokenEx` function.
Set the corresponding values for startupinfo structure

```
si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
```

and called `createprocessasuser`